# What do I need to do to connect to a web service that uses RC4 and High Level SSL Ciphers?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, ssl, iis-6

Our website connects to an external web service, and [it abruptly stopped working last week](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13993703/302677). Upon looking into the problem, it appears that the problem occurred because the web service vendor switched to RC4 and High Level SSL Ciphers, and so now we need to update our web server to be able to communicate with the new security settings.

I'm no expert on web security, so this means absolutely nothing to me. Our website code simply adds the web service as a Web Reference, and connects using all the default settings.

```
request = New ExternalWebService.ProcessRequestService
response = request.processCommand(parameters)
```

This works fine from my Windows XP test environment, but not from our Windows Server 2003 R2 web server running IIS 6.0.

What do I need to install or configure on the web server to be able to connect to an external web service using RC4 and High Level Ciphers?

The site is currently using .Net Framework 2.0, however I can upgrade to 4.0 if needed.

Comment: @SLaks I get a `System.Net.WebException` saying `An unexpected error occurred on a send`. See the [linked SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13993703/302677) for more details on the exact error

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but to be clear, are you using WCF or asmx web services?

Comment: @sll I'm not sure, the external vendor simply publishes the wsdl of their web service and we connect to it via a Web Reference in Visual Studio.

Comment: What they mean under the 'high level SSL ciphers'? RC4 is not 'high level' in any way. The best way is to use Wireshark to see which ciphers requests client, and which ciphers are supported by server.

Comment: What about asking API/service provider about what was done and what shall you do in order to setup security?

Comment: @NickolayO. I believe it's a setting on their Apache web service they can check. They can either set the security to `default` or `High`. I saw it referenced somewhere while I was trying to research this myself, but I can't find the exact reference now.

Comment: @sll I will, I just thought this would be something common as their request to us was `"Are you able to upgrade your security settings that are used to connect to our web service?"`, so thought it was something I'd be able to find out about easily online without bothering them